# remove previos alert message

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using the following code to add message and its working fine,the problem is 
that when I put the second message I see it on top of the preivos message and so on...
there is a way to remove the previos message from the UI when I add new one

```
function addInfoMessage(message) {

    var $msg = $("<div class='alert alert-info'><strong>Information : </strong>" + message + "<button type='button' class='close' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button></div>");
    $messages.append($msg);

}
```

Comment: $messages = $msg?.. If not, can you be more specific about what you are trying to do and what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not append, just replace the content with [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$messages.html($msg);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use in **[empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)** in jQuery to remove all children element

```
 $messages.empty();
 var $msg = $("<div class='alert alert-info'><strong>Information : </strong>" + message + "<button type='button' class='close' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button></div>");
    $messages.append($msg);
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to select the message and remove it, like this:

```
function addInfoMessage(message) {
    $messages.find('.alert.alert-info').remove();
    var $msg = $("<div class='alert alert-info'><strong>Information : </strong>" + message + "<button type='button' class='close' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button></div>");
    $messages.append($msg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.html()` instead of `.append()`, this will replace all html code inside `$messages`

```
function addInfoMessage(message) {

    var $msg = $("<div class='alert alert-info'><strong>Information : </strong>" + message + "<button type='button' class='close' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button></div>");
    $messages.html($msg);

}
```